# Why is Rails ignoring my parameters for this form submission?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I am trying to submit a simplel form in Rails 3, to use with the acts_as_commentable plugin.

```
#new_comment_box
  #comment_input_box
    = form_for :comment,  :url => comments_path(commentable.class.to_s.underscore, commentable.id), :html => {:id => "new_comment"}, :remote => true do |f| 
      #share-input
        = f.text_area :comment, :id => 'comment-input', :'data-text' => "Comment on this review...", :placeholder => "Comment on this review..."
        .cancel
      .clear
      = f.submit 'Comment', :id => 'item-comment-submit', :class => "button"

      .clear
```

My Comment model has a "comment" text attribute, and 
My controller is pretty simple:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :load_commentable

  def create
    pp params[:comment]
    @comment = @commentable.comments.build(params[:comment])
    @comment.user = current_user
    respond_to do |format|
      if @comment.save
        format.html {render :partial => 'comments/comment', :locals  => {:commentable  => @commentable, :comment => @comment}}
      end
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @comment = @commentable.comments.find(params[:id])    
    @comment.destroy
        respond_to do |format|
      format.json {render :json => params[:id]}
    end 
  end

protected

  def load_commentable
    @commentable = params[:commentable_type].camelize.constantize.find(params[:commentable_id])
  end
end
```

Here is the generated HTML:

```
   <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/item/252/comments" data-remote="true" id="new_comment" method="post"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="&#x2713;" /><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden" value="cXgXwhXdMMV38Ye/fIVVrke8pH7iZE/iFY+z4oO2Szs=" /></div> 
        <div id='share-input'> 
          <textarea cols="40" data-text="Comment on this review..." id="comment-input" name="comment[comment]" placeholder="Comment on this review..." rows="20"></textarea> 
          <div class='cancel'></div> 
        </div> 
        <div class='clear'></div> 
        <input class="button" id="item-comment-submit" name="commit" type="submit" value="Comment" /> 
        <div class='clear'></div> 
    </form>
```

and my routes look like this:

```
POST   /:commentable_type/:commentable_id/comments(.:format)          {:action=>"create", :controller=>"comments"}
```

Yet when I try to submit this form, the rails log detects nothing being sumitted:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"cXgddasdMMV38Ye/fIVVrkdfsdpH7iZE/iFYsdfsdfz4oO2Szs=", "comment"=>{"comment"=>""}, "commit"=>"Comment", "commentable_type"=>"item", "commentable_id"=>"252"}
```

Furthermore, it looks from firebug like the request isn't even sending the comments from the page.

Could someone tell me what I'm doing wrong, and why this isn't working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For some reason.. it didn't like having the textarea id as "comment-input".  When I changed it to "comment_comment"  it worked...  would still appreciate an explanation why though

Answer (score 1):

So you figured out yourself why this was failing, which is good.

You shouldn't need to give this a custom `id` attribute as it will already have one called `comment_comment` based on the name of the field. Best not to mess with that.

Unfortunately, I do not know the answer as to *why* it wasn't accepting this weirdly named parameter. The code probably lies within the `rails.js` or `jquery_ujs.js` file in your application.

Comment: Thanks,  just by any chance, do you happen to know where in the Rails codebase it generates these id, class names?   I'd like to read through it to understand the rules behind it

Comment: @Noli: generally it is "[object_class_name]_[field_name]". I do not know where in Rails it generates it, look in the `text_field` or `label` method's code.